# Pyomo with gurobi: opt.solve is not found, returns SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file <stdin>

Tags: python, gurobi, pyomo

After hours and hours tracking the error back and trying a variety of ways, I hope someone would have an idea.

I am implementing an optimization with Pyomo and gurobi as solver. Following code:
    # coding = utf-8

```
from itertools import product

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from CentralOptimizationModel import create_central_optimizer
from Schedules import gen_RES_curve,gen_load_curve,gen_bes_schedules
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import *
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':


print("Create generation and load curves")
externalRES=gen_RES_curve()
clusterLoad=gen_load_curve()

print("Create BES schedules")
BES_schedule_dictionary=gen_bes_schedules()

print("Create the central optimizer for the given cluster information")
start_ModelCreator = time.time()
mod=create_central_optimizer(BES_schedule_dictionary,clusterLoad,externalRES)
end_ModelCreator = time.time()

print("Global Optimization")
opt=SolverFactory("gurobi")
start_Solver = time.time()
opt.options["resultfile=myModel.mps"]
print("Despues de opciones")
results = opt.solve(mod)
end_Solver = time.time()
```

A colleague of mine says the code is working on his comupter, on mine it crashes with

File "C:\Users\Blamblón\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 607, in solve
    "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally
ERROR: "[base]\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", 605, solve
    Solver log:
      File "", line 3
    SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file  on line 3, but no encoding declared;

I tried a variety of things and found out that opt.solve is not accessible at all, opt offers only a few arguments to choose and solve is not one of them.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for this?

Thanks a lot,
IS

Comment: Looks like a unicode issue. Can you reproduce the issue with another solver?

Comment: Also, what version of Pyomo are you using? I recall fixing a similar issue that only seemed to pop up on Windows a while back, so maybe try updating your Pyomo installation. We fixed the problem by adding some additional escape characters to the "script" file we sent gurobi.sh.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, an alternative solution is to use a different interface to Gurobi. If you have gurobi_ampl downloaded, then you can use `SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="nl")`. If you have the Gurobi Python bindings installed (i.e., if you can import gurobipy), then you can use `SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")`.

Comment: Please add your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45093189/2) in an answer, do not add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by altering the interface to gurobi. I extended the line to SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python") and the code is running now.