# Application Error: File "<stdin>", line 3

Tags: python, solver, pyomo, gurobi, glpk

I am trying to change the solver for my optimization problem from glpk to gurobi in order to lower the run time. When executing my model with glpk it works just fine but when trying the same with gurobi I get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 3
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xdf' in file <stdin> on line 3, but no encoding 
declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
ERROR: Solver (gurobi) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ApplicationError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [94], in <cell line: 5>()
  2 solver = pyo.SolverFactory("gurobi")
  4 # Solve model
----> 5 solver_results = solver.solve(model, tee=True)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py:596, in 
OptSolver.solve(self, *args, **kwds)
   594     elif hasattr(_status, 'log') and _status.log:
   595         logger.error("Solver log:\n" + str(_status.log))
--> 596     raise ApplicationError(
   597         "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
   598 solve_completion_time = time.time()
   599 if self._report_timing:

ApplicationError: Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally
```

This is the code for solving the model:

```
# Create solver 
solver = pyo.SolverFactory("gurobi")

# Solve model
solver_results = solver.solve(model, tee=True)
```

Does anyone have a tip for me on how to locate the error? I am not importing a file into my optimisation problem so I don't quite get the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a pyomo bug. Probably it communicates with gurobi through stdin/stdout, but fails to declare the encoding correctly (or at all). Does the answer posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093189/pyomo-with-gurobi-opt-solve-is-not-found-returns-syntaxerror-non-ascii-charac help?

Comment: do you have gurobi installed with a current license?  try `gurobi_cl` from a terminal prompt and see what you get.